# What version of git does GitHub Actions use, and can I set to a specific version?

Tags: git, github-actions

I have a GitHub action that build/tests some code, and during the test it calls out to a git command expecting a relatively new-ish version of git.  I have 2.24.3 on my computer.

The feature is:
`git branch --show-current`

show-current isn't an available option on older versions of git.  GitHub actions fails on this call.

I'm presuming it's using an older version.

How can I know what version its using and can I set it to a newer version?

Comment: Which environment are you using?  `ubuntu-latest`?  `ubuntu-20.04`?  Another OS?

Comment: Found it.... runs on ubuntu-20.04

Comment: Would you mind explaining where you found that information, in case somebody else is looking for it in the future?

Comment: Surely...  In my workflow yaml file there's a publish: runs-on: tag that specifies this version.  I also depend on/import another action with uses: that also has this tag and version, so even if my yaml didn't have it, my uses dependency might be the one picked up.

Comment: Hmm... when I look at the included tools with ubuntu-20.04 it says it includes git 2.30.1.  That should work.  Something's picking up an older version somewhere?

Comment: Call `git version` in the action?

Comment: I posted an answer, but I just saw your most recent comment @Greg (it was collapsed before). Are you able to post your workflow file or a link to the run where it failed?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Git version for each environment in the [actions/virtualenvironments repository](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/c253e7f4d192e492988596167a1d461e99698c13/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-README.md#tools). On the Ubuntu 20.04 environment, the Git version is currently 2.30.2.